# Is it safe to rely on module caching by Nodejs for single instances

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, node-modules

I use the following pattern when I need to make sure that I have a single instance of a class:

```
class DB {    
    constructor() {
        // create db connection
    }
}

const myDB = new DB();
export default myDB;
```

So that even if I import it multiple other modules, I get the same instance. Is this a reliable pattern? I know that module caching comes with the file case sensitivity caveat. But are there any edge cases that could cause my multiple imports to create multiple `db` objects?

I know that I can alternatively create a concrete singleton, with a `getInstance()` method but this pattern looks simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are cached by file name in node. But caching is case sensitive. require("./Bar") and require("./bar") returns two different object

https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats